# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, configuration

I have the following configuration for a WCF service.

Even though I have increased the maxReceivedMessageSize , service still throws an error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.`" exception.

How can this be solved?

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:22230/MyService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding"
              contract="IMyService" />

        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyServiceBinding"
               hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
               sendTimeout="00:10:00"
               openTimeout="00:10:00"
               closeTimeout="00:10:00"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
               maxBufferSize="6553600"
               maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
               transferMode="Buffered"
               messageEncoding="Text"
               textEncoding="utf-8"
               bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
               useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel
```

Comment: My theory is that your client config is not correctly configured.

Comment: so u saying, this is correct and should work? My Client is WCFTestClient right now.

Comment: There are a handful of ideas in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f1ad96bf-c5a0-4e6f-a357-0957d32cf2e5), some of which don't apply (e.g. you already increased maxBufferSize as well), but would probably be worth looking at more closely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If this is the service config, you should look in your client config and match the maxReceivedMessageSize to the servers message size. The message is coming from your client.

Comment: Then you have to change the config of the WCFTestClient (go to tools and options) or send less data to the WCFTestClient.

Comment: to change the config of wcf Test Client (FW 4.0 at my case)
you should right click on the config the lowest file in the list of files tree at the left.
the select "Edit with SvcConfigEditor" then select Binding . in the binding element inside find the 3 fellows marked here.
is set it to 2MB as a reasonable size.
http://i.imgur.com/eBdguoy.png

Answer (score 4):

You need to increase the max message size in your client config.  The default is 65536, doubling it may be sufficient for your needs.

If you are configuring your endpoints programmatically, the following code snippet may help:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding() { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 131072 };
```

Then, when instantiating your service client, pass in this binding object to the constructor.  For example:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, "http://www.mysite.com/MyService/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you copy the new App.config