# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded- in wcf service

Tags: wcf

I am writing the wcf service to get the data from sql db. It is returning me near about 2000 rows with 14 columns. I'm getting error as 'The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.'
my web.config is-

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      transferMode="Buffered">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="GetSqlData1.Service1">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
      contract="GetSqlData1.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232355/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please add this line to your serviceBehaviors section:-

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
```

See the sample below.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <!-- Please add this line -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Hi, Request you to please share the client side config file. Seems like your client settings are the cause of the problem.

Comment: Actually i'm using this wcf service monikar to show data in excel using macro. So I don't have the client config. I have single web.config